# How to make an additional in-game content download (patching) for first time launching the Mobile Store Game?

Tags: unity, patching

this is a pretty common but I googled everywhere and nothing.

When there is a game with very big download size, more than 500MB for example,

I often saw that the additional game content is being downloaded during first time launched.

Pretty common, most of the mobile game did this.

But I am wondering how can I did these in Unity? that split the game content out from the deployed game package? or is this method offered in Unity Plus/Pro? not Personal?